# Neomutt can't see my folders after OS upgrade

Tags: filesystems, email

I've been running `offlineimap` and `neomutt` together for several years, but after my last OS update, from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 `neomutt` is not able to see any of my folders and occasionally it will report that it cannot write to my Mail folder.

`offlineimap` seems to work fine. I can read and send mail, but if I try to access a different folder, only my INBOX is visible.

[image: Screenshot of chdir dialog]

When I look in `~/Mail` however, my folders are all there:

[image: Screenshot of output of ls Mail]

[image: Screenshot of output of ls -alh Mail]

This has all "just worked" for so long that I'm not even sure how to begin troublshooting it.

Why would `neomutt` suddenly be unable to read/write files and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Depending how you have neomutt configured usually those folders are set either in your neomuttrc or sometimes in a serperate file and then sourced by a folder hook this is normally done if you have multiple accounts.  Either way the folders are set similarly to the example below I would check the files in `~/.config/neomutt/neomuttrc`.  NOTE: neomutt also checks for fallback configs in the `~/.config/mutt/muttrc` and also in your home directory `.muttrc` or `.neomuttrc`.

```
set spoolfile = ~/Mail/Gmail/INBOX
set record = ~/Mail/Gmail/Sent
set trash = ~/Mail/Gmail/Trash
set postponed = ~/Mail/Gmail/Drafts
```

Using the names you supplied it would be something like.

```
set spoolfile = ~/Mail/INBOX
set record = ~/Mail/INBOX.Sent
set trash = ~/Mail/Gmail/INBOX.Trash
set postponed = ~/Mail/INBOX.Drafts
```

Hope this helps if you need anything else just ask.

EDIT: Please note this is just example you will have to edit the names to match your locations.